# RStudio starts up with error CondaValueError: prefix already exists: C:\Users\myname\ANACON~1\envs\r-reticulate >

Tags: r, rstudio

When I start Rstudio, I get the error message

CondaValueError: prefix already exists: C:\Users\myname\ANACON~1\envs\r-reticulate

This is RStudio 2023.09.0 Build 463, with R 4.3.1 on Windows 11.

What is this error, and how do I get rid of it?

I have reinstalled RStudio, without avail.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have an .Rprofile file in your home directory? It sounds like you setup a startup script at some point that should no longer be there. Reinstalling RStudio won't remove any start up scripts you may have in your home directory. See all the possible different locations for these scripts in the `?Startup` help page.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I don't have a .Rprofile file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by uninstalling Anaconda Navigator. Many thanks.